# Is it realistic that Jimmy's friend from the district attorney's office is so poor?

Tags: realism, better-call-saul

In Better Call Saul S03E03, Jimmy sits next to his old friend Bill Oakley (played by Peter Diseth) who is a Deputy District Attorney. Jimmy pulls out a burger and fries for lunch, while Oakley's lunch is simply two bags of potato chips. These details were clearly intentional to highlight how poor Oakley is (not working for a private law firm).

Up to this point, I had been extremely impressed with how accurate Breaking Bad and Better Call Saul had been with everything, and the exquisite effort put into making things realistic, but it was a shock to see this particular choice for highlighting Oakley's lack of affluence.

According to [this source](http://www.lawcrossing.com/salaries/q-deputy-district-attorney-l-New-Mexico-jobs.html), the average Deputy District Attorney in New Mexico makes $60,000/year which I would think is enough to buy a decent lunch in Mexico, but without the help of user feedback, it's unlikely we can find what the spread of that average is (for example if Oakley is not the most diligent attorney, his salary could be significantly lower).

Comment: I don't see what is unrealistic about it. If $60k is the average then we have to consider that its possible that he might make at least $10k less than that. I think its perfectly reasonable to assume that he might be scrimping on lunch money to be able to cover other expenses.

Comment: Anything is "possible". I wonder why the director went through such great effort to demonstrate how poor the Deputy District Attorney is. Are DDAs  seriously so poor?

Comment: Add a mortgage and a couple of kids and that $60k won't sound so big anymore...

Comment: @JonathanReez: True, but that's also true for all sorts of people. The director seemed to go out of their way to show that lawyers that are not working for a big firm, live very poor lifestyles. It was similar when Jimmy (Saul) was was a public defender and then later a private practitioner working out of a room upstairs from a nail salon.

Comment: The stingiest are not the poorest :)

Comment: @user1271772: `Jimmy (Saul) was was a public defender and then later a private practitioner` While Jimmy's days in the nail salon were not glamorous; he was not as overworked compared to when he was a public defender. At least working privately; he had an easier schedule and clients on an extended basis (as opposed to brief client interactions as a public defender). That is the difference between Bill and Jimmy in the scene you're talking about. Compare a painter painting as many walls as he can (Bill) and an expert painter who's painting less walls with more skill and thus better pay (Jimmy).

Comment: @user1271772: A better example, come to think of it, would be comparing a fast food cook (Bill), who tries to make cheap burgers as fast as he can to serve the masses. Jimmy, on the other hand, has opened his own restaurant; where the prices are higher but this means Jimmy puts real effort into the food because he's not trying to churn out as many burgers as he can. If you've ever worked in both types of jobs (not necessarily food or law), you should know what the difference feels like. It is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$60K may seem like a decent wage, but when you add the additional debt carried for 3 years of law school, plus county government isn't going to buy the suits you need to wear to court (business casual that the average $60K office stiff can wear is not an option).... that's not a great return on that particular investment.

Average debt for college grads with loans is about $30K, as of a couple year ago.

[USA Today: Average college debt, state by state](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/personalfinance/2017/04/28/average-student-loan-debt-every-state/100893668/)

Average debt for law school grads who have loans is $148K.

[US News and World Report: Graduate Debt](https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-law-schools/grad-debt-rankings)

Comment: I accepted your answer, but perhaps you can remove the part that implies that a suit from a thrift store costs thousands of dollars :)

Comment: @user1271772 - nowhere do I imply that a suit from a thrift store costs thousands.  But (A) if you have to buy your suits from a thrift store, you're not making a ton of money, and (B) a suit from a thrift store is still going to cost a lot more than a collared sports shirt ($15 to $20 brand new) that you can wear with jeans in a business casual office.

Comment: you're wrong about everything there, you implied that a suit from a thrift store would cost a significant portion of $60,000, then you said that you didn't imply that, then you said that a suit from a thrift store would cost more than $15 which is false, and it is also not true that business casual suits that the average staff (not stiff, as the original version of your answer says) can wear is not acceptable for a lawyer.

Comment: @user1271772 -  I'm wrong about what I intended and had in mind when I was typing, because you know better?  Get outta here. A suit, acceptable to wear into court for a legal professional (no DA's boss will accept that) will not be procured at $15, and you can't wear the same one every day. And, no, I never said that it would cost a significant portion of the $60K. Pre-tax $60K, a soda is a significant proportion. I juxtaposed it to what someone working in a regular business casual environment would cost, pointing out of pocket professional expenses are more. Nothing more. Nothing less.

Comment: Remember, your question was about realism. Judges send attorneys home for skirts too short. Threaten contempt for wearing an ascot instead of a tie. From the DAs office, they definitely would expect a certain standard. If your biggest beef is that I point out dressing for court costs a bit more than the business casual office environment, you need to take a step back and re-evaluate things.

Comment: A business casual suit, is not a skirt too short.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "business casual suit". "Business casual," by definition, precludes suits.  I think we're done here.

Comment: ["**Business-Casual-3-pieces-Suit**", $66](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/JOYWEI-Men-s-Suit-Business-Casual-3-pieces-Suit-Blazer-Pants-VestMen-s-Suit-Business-Casual-3-pieces-Suit-Blazer-Pants-Vest/PRD5UGIZ5E8STL5), [Men's **Business Casual Suit**, $66](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/Surrme-Men-s-Suit-Business-Casual-Suit-Blazer-Wedding-Party-Festive-ClothingMen-s-Suit-Business-Casual-Suit-Blazer-Wedding-Party-Festive-Clothing/PRD7BE18Q18GI4P).

Comment: [**Business Casual Fashion Tuxedo**, $140](https://www.amazon.ca/Business-Casual-Fashion-Tuxedos-Blazer/dp/B0C1RFPTNJ), [Three-Piece **Business Casual Suit**, $2000](https://www.amazon.ca/Three-Piece-Business-Professional-British-Wedding/dp/B0BZJGHDM3).

Comment: There is no such thing as a "business casual tuxedo," or a "business casual suit."  The definition of business casual is no ties, no coats, no suits, and certainly no tuxedos.  If a company wants to misuse a term for God knows what reason, good for them. But the very definition of "business casual" is what it is. And get serious, those are NOT business casual outfits.

I can find business that completely misuse terms for their products anywhere. You're being silly now.

https://ung.edu/career-services/online-career-resources/interview-well/professional-vs-casual.php

Comment: You don't get to decide what "business casual" means or doesn't mean. Neither do I. I recommended you to remove the poor-quality part of your answer, and it seems that the best word to describe how you've reacted to that is "stubborn".

Comment: @user1271772 - As you can see from the links I provided, it's not ***ME*** that is trying to redefine what "business casual: means.  These are universities advising graduating students going to interviews and entering the workplace, telling them what it means, and there are countless articles from business resources saying the same thing.  Get serious.

Comment: The link you provided was not from a dictionary, but instead from an unprofessional website from one of the lowest-quality universities in the world, and ***still*** it doesn't support your opinion at all: they literally say that the terms "business professional" and "business casual" are ***not*** well-defined and that business professional in one place could be business casual in another place. They do not agree with you about business casual not including a tie (notice the words ***if*** and ***may*** in their sentence). Then you lied about it being more than one university.

Comment: @user1271772 - **The ENTIRE POINT OF THE CONCEPT OF BUSINESS CASUAL** is not wearing a suit or even a tie. How far one goes with "casual" may not be well-defined, but the fact that it's absolutely not a suit is not. Funny that you criticize the quality of my links, when all you offer is some fashion marketing description, as if that's authoritative. "Business casual tuxedo"??  Seriously?  Give it up.

Comment: Do not yell at me. Also, not only was your source from an extremely low quality university, it literally said the opposite of what you were trying to prove.

Comment: @user1271772 - And you only source was..... nothing. But, if finding professional advice from a university isn't good enough, here's what ***HARVARD*** says - ***"Business casual is the default attire for career fairs and networking events. This includes button down/collared shirts, polished sweaters, khakis and dress slacks and a tailored dress or skirt. Avoid sneakers and informal sandals like flip flops."*** It's not like I picked that other source because it was the only one that supported what I was saying. You don't know what you are talking about. Give it up.

Comment: https://careerservices.fas.harvard.edu/resources/mcs-professional-attire-guide/  "business formal" is a suit. Business casual is, pretty obviously to most people, less formal than a suit.  So, not a suit.

Comment: @user1271772 - Remember the original point of contention - you pretending that the expectation and expense for dressing to the standards of arguing in a court of law, as a lawyer, would not be more than a business casual office environment. It's absurd.

Comment: If you did not pick the no-name university because it was the only one that supported what you were saying, then why did you pick it? Why did you not show the Harvard link the first time? Also, I didn't say "business casual" in my initial comment. I said "suit". You kept saying "business casual", so in my next comment I said "business casual suit". It's not a term that I use often, and I would have just called it "suit". **My real initial point was that a suit does not cost more than $60,000**. Any sane person earning $60,000/year can afford the clothing required for court. That is the point.

Comment: @user1271772 - Because it was the first on a long list of search results that popped up, none of which refuted any of the others. Why does it matter which one I picked? Does the fact that I picked that one first somehow negate that Harvard, THE most prestigious university when it comes to business in the world, says exactly the same thing?  That's some serious deflection on your part. You offered what you thought was a fatally deadly rebuttal point, and it wound up being completely turned on you, so now you want to invent some external factor to dismiss it.

Comment: You're the one deflecting right now.

Comment: @user1271772 - Brilliant straw-man.  No one ever claimed that a suit costs more than $60,000, so if that's "your original point," then you never had a point to start with. For the debt they have to incur going to law school that they have to contend with, and compared to the salaries of others practicing law in the same court rooms, $60K is, very much, on the low end of compensation for practicing law. FROM YOUR OWN SOURCE, the average litigation attorney, anywhere, makes $85K+.  Average.

Comment: Your words: "business casual that the average $60K office stiff can wear is not an option". A decent suit is an option right? **Can someone earning $60k afford a suit?**

Comment: @user1271772 - Brilliant "I know you are but what am I" response, but I'm very directly responding to the exact points and questions you are offering.  I said "business casual" because the average office worker, making $60K, doesn't have to spend that kind of money on the minimum professional attire expected. I was pointing out that there is additional financial overhead that comes with practicing law, overall and in general. You are the one who immediately invented the phony claim that I was saying that this would run thousands of dollars.

Comment: @user1271772 - I'm was never saying that you can't buy a suit on a $60K salary, I'm pointing out that someone who earns $60K in an office where they can wear jeans, polo shirt and sneakers, has less professional overhead, on a constant basis, than someone who can be held in contempt of court if they are not attired in a suit, tie and in good enough condition to not be deemed disrespectful by the presiding judge. Keep offering straw man arguments that I never, ever made. It bolsters your claims of not deflecting so very strongly. Also why I juxtaposed average college debt vs law degree debt.

Comment: **"on a constant basis"**, most lawyers on a $60k/year salary won't be buying suits on "a constant basis".

Comment: @user1271772 - People have to buy new clothes periodically over time, for as long as they work. If you prefer perpetual vs constant, that's fair. More importantly, as you continue your trend to fixate on the irrelevant, is that the person in jeans, sneakers and polo shirts is replacing their less expensive wardrobe on a schedule/rotation that would have no reason to be any different. The point is that the difference in costs would not be a one-time thing. Cleaning costs tend to be more for suits, as well. That is pretty constant.

Comment: **Anyone that is earning $60,000/year can afford the clothing required to be a lawyer if they spend reasonably wisely.**

Comment: Again, never claimed they couldn't afford the clothing, just that, compared to other attorneys making more, and even to others making the same in an environment with less overhead, there's less money left over to pick up lunch tabs. **Again**, to the original point, are you still claiming that it doesn't cost more to work in business professional attire work environment vs business casual, smart casual or full casual environment?  Because that's simply wrong, and I really don't understand your unwillingness to accept the very, very obvious.

Comment: My original point is: **Anyone that is earning $60,000/year can afford the clothing required to be a lawyer if they spend reasonably wisely.** I suggested that you remove the part in your answer that disagrees with that, in my first comment. You seem to think that it's extremely important to stay in the answer though.

Comment: Not sure why you keep pretending that I ever said someone making $60K can't afford to buy suits. I never, ever said that. Please stop with the gaslighting and straw man characterizations. The original question you posed is that is it really accurate to say that someone making $60K as a lawyer isn't comfortably affluent, particularly compared to someone with a highly specialized and successful self-owned practice?  And the answer is yes, it is accurate. The "and the county isn't going to buy you suits" was just to illustrate some of the additional overhead someone would have in that profession.

Comment: **I never said "comfortably affluent" anywhere.**

Comment: @user1271772 - You questioned the juxtaposition of relative wealth between Jimmy and his friend. Jimmy is very going very well, financially. If Bill is much worse off, then you are questioning whether it's accurate that his isn't financially comfortable on $60K. $60K is well below the median household income in the USA. The debt from law school is much greater than the average debt most workers carry in the USA. Overhead costs, which we're bickering about, are more for a lawyer than your average office worker making $60K. It adds up. "Poor" was your own inference about the potato chips.

Comment: "The debt from law school is much greater than the average debt most workers carry in the USA" this is why I accepted your answer, along with the part in which you said "**Average debt for law school grads who have loans is $148K**". Mentioning the cost of suits makes this a much worse answer than it could be. The cost of a suit is a bit more than the cost of clothing for an average non-lawyer, but that is such an irrelevant detail when the lawyer has on average a debt of $118,000 more. What are the annual interest payments on $118,000 vs the annual cost of a suit vs ordinary office clothes?

Comment: @user1271772 - because, contrary to your continued straw man arguments, I never made any claim that it was a central feature. It was a quick example of one kind of cost, and salary alone tells us nothing without the context of cost. I don't have to wear a suit at my job. But my company even supplies free branded business casual work attire, because they like having the brand on display. County governments don't have enough to hire enough attorneys, or pay them a competitive wage, so that's a cost that the lawyer has to pick up. You're familiar with the concept of offering an example, right?

Comment: @user1271772 - As others have pointed out with your personal interpretation that potato chips MUST mean impoverished, you have a knack of making your own unfounded assumptions and interpretations about what people say, and exaggerating them as unrefutable fact. This back and forth is completely filled with you arguing against things I never said or suggested. Work on that. It's somewhat unpleasant to have to deal with.

Comment: The question was **"What are the annual interest payments on $118,000 vs the difference in annual cost between suits and ordinary office clothes?"** and your response was "because, contrary to your continued straw man arguments, I never made any claim that it was a central feature." I hope these were your last two comments. You find me "unpleasant" yet you've prolonged this conversation for about 5 months. It would have been a lot less unpleasant if you removed the weakest part of your answer, but it seems that your desire to defend that part is greater than my unpleasantries, so here we are.

Comment: That was never a question of any kind, so thank you for confirming your particular fetish with straw man arguments.

Comment: On Nov 27 at 23:48 the question "What are the annual interest payments on $118,000 vs the difference in annual cost between suits and ordinary office clothes?" was asked, and your response was "That was never a question of any kind".

Comment: THE question was and is "Is it realistic that Jimmy's friend from the district attorney's office is so poor?" Again, I only brought up the issue of professional attire to make the point that $60K in one profession is not the same as $60K in a profession that has more personal overhead.  Get help.

Comment: Okay I will get help, and okay $60k in one profession is not the same as $60k in another,  but your answer still has the error that it implies that $60k isn't enough to buy a suit.

Comment: My answer never implies anything of the sort, which, again, is why you need to seek help since you are so fixated on that completely false notion.  My answer says "**plus the county isn't going to buy you the suits**" - that doesn't imply you can't afford them on 60K, it says that's an additional expense that comes out of pocket.  ***AGAIN*** - in the full context it's merely giving an example of some expenses that a "business casual" office worker isn't incurring out of pocket from their 60K salary.

Comment: The fact that you mentioned it means that you think the cost of a suit is a serious affordability problem for lawyers who earn $60k/year. Almost everyone already has a suit, and otherwise can get one from a thrift store for less than 0.25% of 1 year's salary. That suit then lasts for several years and turns out to be a tiny fraction (maybe 0.01%) of the total earnings for someone such as the lawyer mentioned in my question. The part about affordability of suits is the largest part of your answer and yet it is the least relevant. Your answer would be improved if you removed it.

Comment: The fact that I mentioned it merely meant that I felt like giving some relatable examples, nothing more. I could have just as easily said "shoes" or "briefcases," but attire was a specific thing from "My Cousin Vinny," so I thought it would resonate more easily with others. Again, you are making mind-reading assumptions that have no basis in reality. Focus more on getting that help you need. The ***AVERAGE*** pay for a trial attorney New Mexico is $113K. An assistant DA making $60K is not doing well compared to peers, financially, no matter how much you want to pretzel-twist it.

Comment: If you said "shoes" or "briefcases", it would have still been irrelevant, because compared to the $60k that he likely earns each year (and the $600k he'd likely earn after 10 years in the career), spending a few dozen dollars on shoes is not going to make him so poor that he can't afford a lunch (beyond two small bags of potato chips). As for not doing well compared to his peers: I agree that he's not doing well compared to them, but that doesn't explain why he couldn't afford lunch, so this too is off-topic and irrelevant (not doing well compared to peers doesn't mean "can't afford lunch").

Answer (score 7):

I had a slightly different interpretation of that scene. I don't think the details of the scene were meant to highlight how *poor* DDA Oakley is. I think they're meant to show that he's still stuck in the same grind (although on the opposite side) that Jimmy used to be stuck in when he was a public defender. It's not so much that he can't afford a cafeteria burger, just that he's kept so busy that he doesn't have time for more than a vending machine lunch between cases.

Comment: He did not seem to be in a rush at all , and when Jimmy left, he was very excited to accept Jimmy's offer to finish his burger. Jimmy left, and Bill stayed there to enjoy the burger. He also had time to go all the way to the police station to see Jimmy when he was being detained.

Comment: @user1271772 Why would he seem to be in a rush? Weren't they sitting outside the court room?

Comment: I just remember them sitting on a bench, perhaps in court. However, he did not seem like he was "so busy that he doesn't have time for more than a vending machine lunch between cases". If he has so many cases to prosecute, he might have at least a folder in his hand with some notes that he could review for the next case, or some work he could do in advance for another upcoming case. He doesn't strike me as the type of guy that was "so busy he couldn't buy lunch".

Comment: @user1271772: Your proposed option of what it would look like if he has a busy job is only one of many options. He may have made time to talk to Jimmy, an old friend. Maybe he had a slower day. Maybe he had an hour until the next trial started. Your singular example is not the only possible explanation for him being "in the daily grind of being a public defender". The point Bill the Lizard makes is not that Bill is _excessively busy_; but rather than Bill is still doing "bulk processing" as a public defender; as opposed to Jimmy's work which has fewer clients and less need for court trials.

Answer (score 3):

> ...is it realistic that Jimmy's friend from the district attorney's
>   office is so poor?

Why not? Maybe he is not really **poor**, just stingy.
We have no real deep background infos about Oakley.

Maybe he has/is:

- 6 kids
- 3 ex-wifes
- expensive wife or/and girlfriend
- gambling-addicted
- very stingy
- high mortgage(s)
- many insurances, PayTV, expensive hobbies, ...

It doesn't matter **how much you earn** if the **expenses were higher than the income**.

Comment: Absolutely true, but the director went way out of their way to emphasize this point that Jimmy can afford a burger but Bill needs to eat two bags of potato chips as if it were a lunch. I'm wondering what the reason for this was.

Comment: @user1271772 _"the director went way out of their way to emphasize this point that Jimmy can **afford** a burger"_ The scene does not pull into focus the _financial_ aspect. You're reading that into the scene. There are many reasons for the two men to have a different lunch. The exact reason for that is never specified. You're right that the difference in lunch is stressed, but the _reason_ for the difference in lunch is never explored.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in meal isn't intended to specifically prove a wealth gap between Jimmy and Bill. It helps paint the difference between Jimmy and Bill, especially in regards to quality of life.

Jimmy may complain about his life/career, but when you compared the freedoms he has as an independent lawyer to the life of a public prosecutor, you can't help but think that Jimmy's focusing on the bad (not being as rich or successful as Chuck/Howard) more than the good (having it better than Bill).

Bill is an ex-colleague of Jimmy. **The main goal of the scene is to show you the difference between past Jimmy and present Jimmy**. Bill is merely a representative of what Jimmy's past looked like.

The scene is short, so Bill's character is explained in broad strokes:

- Incredibly busy job, daily grind.
- Unrewarding clients.
- He can't do better than a bag of chips for lunch. Notice that this isn't necessarily a financial obstable for Bill. There are other reasons for this:

  - Bill has so many cases that he doesn't have the time to go out for lunch and instead has to settle for the nearest vending machine.
  - Much like his career, Bill's food habits are unhealthy and mismanaged. He never aspires for something better. Maybe he complains about his life, but never truly takes action to fix it.
  - Money can also be an issue here, but it seems unlikely to be the sole deciding factor here.

---

To paint the picture more explicitly:

Effectively, Jimmy's holding a burger, begrudgingly looking over (in his mind) at Chuck and Howard who are having a nice steak for lunch. Why does Chuck/Howard get to have a fancy lunch and he only get a burger?

However, behind Jimmy is Bill, who is holding a vending machine pack of chips, begrudgingly looking over at Jimmy who's having a nice burger for lunch. Why does Jimmy get to have a fancy lunch and he only get a bag of chips?

---

Jimmy is a flawed man. We know this because we know where he ends up in Breaking Bad. Jimmy *doesn't* make the right choices, and Jimmy *doesn't* make it big in the end. Just like Walter White, Jimmy will make the wrong choices for (what he thinks are) the right reasons.

This scene is one of the red flags that shows you one of Jimmy's flaws. **He's so fixated on others he competes with (Chuck/Howard), that he completely forgets that while he's not *as* successful as Chuck/Howard, he's still more successful than he was in the past.**

*This effectively mirrors Walter White's flaw. When he reached the initial goal (getting enough money for his family), he then started competing with other major players because he wanted the territory and fame that comes with being a kingpin. Jimmy is on a similar quest for greatness and forgets about the things he's already achieved.*

Answer (score 1):

> Oakley's lunch is simply two bags of potato chips. These details were clearly intentional to highlight how poor Oakley is

Your above interpretation is wrong. Instead,

1. Oakley is not poor.
2. Those details were not to "highlight how poor Oakley is".
3. Those details were merely to depict the human being that is Oakley.

Human beings are varied and complex (as the creators of both this show and Breaking Bad try to depict with their varied characters).

Eating two bags of potato chips for lunch does not mean you are poor. It could (but need not) simply mean for example:

1. You don't care too much about your health.
2. You like to have a rushed lunch so you can go back to do your work.
3. You are unusually thrifty.
4. You like potato chips.

Etc. Etc. Etc.

---

Warren Buffett eats McDonald's for breakfast everyday (which in 2017, never cost more than $3.17):

> I tell my wife, as I shave in the morning, I say, ‘Either $2.61, $2.95 or $3.17.’ And she puts that amount in the little cup by me here [in the car] ([CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/01/30/warren-buffetts-breakfast-never-costs-more-than-317.html))

If you observed this guy having McDonald's every morning, you might incorrectly interpret that he is poor too.